# Android: Unable to pause activity ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: NowPlayingFragmentBottom

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

I got these error when I pressed any song how to solve this!! I got these java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error. please anyone?

> NowPlayingFragmentBottom

```
public class NowPlayingFragmentBottom extends Fragment implements ServiceConnection {
    
      ImageView nextBtn, prevBtn, albumArt;
      TextView artist, songName;
      FloatingActionButton playPauseBtn;
    
      View view;
      MusicService musicService;
    
        public static final String MUSIC_LAST_PLAYED = "LAST_PLAYED";
        public static final String MUSIC_FILE = "STORED_MUSIC";
        public static final String ARTIST_NAME = "ARTIST NAME";
        public static final String SONG_NAME = "SONG NAME";
        public NowPlayingFragmentBottom() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing_bottom, container, false);
    
            artist = view.findViewById(R.id.song_artist_miniPlayer);
            songName = view.findViewById(R.id.song_name_miniPlayer);
            nextBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.skip_next_bottom);
            prevBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.skip_prev_bottom);
            albumArt = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_album_art);
            playPauseBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_miniPlayer);
            //prev , next , playpause
            prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    if(musicService != null){
                        musicService.prevBtnClicked();
    
                        if(getActivity() != null) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MUSIC_LAST_PLAYED, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString(MUSIC_FILE, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getPath());
                            editor.putString(ARTIST_NAME, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getArtist());
                            editor.putString(SONG_NAME, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getTitle());
                            editor.apply();
    
                            SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MUSIC_LAST_PLAYED,MODE_PRIVATE);
                            String path = preferences.getString(MUSIC_FILE,null);
                            String artistName = preferences.getString(ARTIST_NAME,null);
                            String song_name = preferences.getString(SONG_NAME,null);
    
                            if(path != null){
                                SHOW_MINI_PLAYER = true;
                                PATH_TO_FRAGMENT = path;
                                ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT = artistName;
                                SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT = song_name;
                            }
                            else{
                                SHOW_MINI_PLAYER = false;
                                PATH_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                                ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                                SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                            }
    
                            if (SHOW_MINI_PLAYER ){
    
                                if(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT !=null) {
    
                                    byte[] art = getAlbumArt(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT);
    
                                    if(art != null) {
                                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                                .load(art)
                                                .into(albumArt);
                                    }
                                    else {
    
                                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                                .load(R.drawable.m2)
                                                .into(albumArt);
                                    }
                                    songName.setText(SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT);
                                    artist.setText(ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT);
    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }}
            });
```

> > I got these error when I pressed any song how to solve this!! I got these java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error. please anyone?

```
            nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(musicService != null){
                        musicService.nextBtnClicked();
    
                        if(getActivity() != null) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MUSIC_LAST_PLAYED, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString(MUSIC_FILE, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getPath());
                            editor.putString(ARTIST_NAME, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getArtist());
                            editor.putString(SONG_NAME, musicService.musicFiles.get(musicService.position).getTitle());
                            editor.apply();
    
                            SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MUSIC_LAST_PLAYED,MODE_PRIVATE);
                            String path = preferences.getString(MUSIC_FILE,null);
                            String artistName = preferences.getString(ARTIST_NAME,null);
                            String song_name = preferences.getString(SONG_NAME,null);
    
                            if(path != null){
                                SHOW_MINI_PLAYER = true;
                                PATH_TO_FRAGMENT = path;
                                ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT = artistName;
                                SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT = song_name;
    
                            }
                            else{
                                SHOW_MINI_PLAYER = false;
                                PATH_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                                ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                                SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT = null;
                            }
    
                            if (SHOW_MINI_PLAYER){
    
                                if(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT !=null) {
    
                                    byte[] art = getAlbumArt(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT);
    
                                    if(art != null) {
                                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                                .load(art)
                                                .into(albumArt);
                                    }
                                    else {
    
                                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                                .load(R.drawable.m2)
                                                .into(albumArt);
                                    }
                                    songName.setText(SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT);
                                    artist.setText(ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT);
    
                                }
    
                            }
    
                        }
    
                    }
                }
            });
    
            playPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(musicService != null){
    
                        musicService.playPauseBtnClicked();
    
                        if(musicService.isPlaying()){
                            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                        }
                        else{
                            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (SHOW_MINI_PLAYER){
    
                if(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT !=null) {
    
                    byte[] art = getAlbumArt(PATH_TO_FRAGMENT);
    
                    if(art != null) {
                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                .load(art)
                                .into(albumArt);
                    }
                    else {
                        Glide.with(getContext())
                                .load(R.drawable.m2)
                                .into(albumArt);
                    }
                    songName.setText(SONG_NAME_TO_FRAGMENT);
                    artist.setText(ARTIST_TO_FRAGMENT);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),MusicService.class);
                    if(getContext() != null){
                        getContext().bindService(intent,this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    }
                }
    
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(getContext() != null ){
                getContext().unbindService(this);
            }
        }
        private  byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri)
        {
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(uri);
            byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            retriever.release();
            return  art;
        }
   
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MyBinder myBinder = (MusicService.MyBinder) service;
            musicService = myBinder.getService();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicService = null;
        }
    }
```

> logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.musicplayer/com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: NowPlayingFragmentBottom{6943cbf} (57d50a80-8e02-4b9c-8455-ad91860cbc9d id=0xffffffff)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4503)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4406)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:46)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: NowPlayingFragmentBottom{6943cbf} (57d50a80-8e02-4b9c-8455-ad91860cbc9d id=0xffffffff)
    at com.example.musicplayer.Fragments.NowPlayingFragmentBottom.onPause(NowPlayingFragmentBottom.java:259)
```

> > here , I post the logcat, where show service is not registered but I  don't understand where the issue is happening. What is the issue?